# Batch file for 2 workbooks

Tags: excel, batch-file

I have 2 workbooks in the same folder.
OldTimesheet.xls
NewTimesheet.xls

I need to run a batch file that will copy a range from a worksheet tab in OldTimesheet.xls, and put the data to NewTimesheet.xls worksheet tab.

Then, Batch file will make a copy of NewTimesheet.xls in another folder.

Or copy row from Oldtimesheet.xls to Newtimesheet.xls.

Comment: A batch file is not the appropriate solution for copying rows or ranges of data between spreadsheets. It will work for making the copy in a different folder, but not for altering the contents of the workbook. You'll need a different solution for that task.

Comment: thank you Ken. Would i have to use SSIS. Do you know another alternative?

Comment: What does SSIS have to do with Excel? You can use VBA in Excel, COM automation from any language that supports it, or several other ways, but I see no mention of SQL Server anywhere in your question. What does SQL Server have to do with anything here?